# How jsdoc describes static class method which returns SAME CLASS variable

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

This is very simple example of what I want to get. My question is about @returns tag. What should I write there?

```js
class Base{
  /**
  * @returns {QUESTION: WHAT SHOUL BE HIRE??}
  */
  static method(){
    return new this()
  }
}

class Sub extends Base{
}

let base= Base.method() // IDE should understand that base is instance of Base
let sub= Sub.method() // IDE should understand that sub is instance of Sub
```

Comment: I believe there is no way to do this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "relative" type.
You could fairly trivally modify the extended class;

```
/** @extends {Base} */
class Sub extends Base{
  /**  @returns {Sub} */
  static method(){
    return super.method();
  }
}
```

Or perhaps use a third type, an `@interface` that defines this method's existence

```
/** @interface */
class I {
  method() {}
}
/** @implements {I} */
class Base {
  /**  @returns {I} */
  static method(){
    return new this();
  }
}

/** 
 * @extends {Base}
 * @implements {I}
 */
class Sub {
  /**  @returns {I} */
  static method(){
    return new this();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old question and that in most circumstances projects needing a polymorphic this for static methods would now be using TypeScript with the workaround as listed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-752874483).

Several of our browser based projects are still using pure ES module JavaScript without any build step and introducing a build step for this use case seems over the top. On these projects we are also using Visual Studio Code's 'Implicit Project Config: Check JS' to enable type checking. Having to cast the return of every extended static method is a real pain!

The following workaround works well in Visual Studio Code for JavaScript with JSDoc:

[image]

```js
/**
 * @template  T
 * @param {T} Class
 * @returns {{
 *   method: () => InstanceType<T>
 *  } & T}
 */
// @ts-ignore
const fixPolymorphicThis = Class => Class

class Base {
    static method() {
        return new this()
    }
}
const Sub = fixPolymorphicThis(class Sub extends Base { })

let base = Base.method() // IDE should understand that base is instance of Base
let sub = Sub.method() // IDE should understand that sub is instance of Sub

console.assert(sub instanceof Base)
console.assert(sub instanceof Sub)
```